# I have some serious problems with the new Input System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, 2d-games

I'm making a 2D platformer with Unity. It's been 3 weeks since I decided to use the new Input System (with the Player Input component) to add gamepad and keyboard support but I'm still struggling with it.

To add those features, I decided to use [a Player Controller code from GitHub](https://github.com/LooveToLoose/platformer-controls-test/blob/master/Assets/PlayerMovement.cs) as a guide; but the problem is that it's using the old Input System. So, I need to change the code a little bit.

But I don't know how to write the equivalent of `(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"))` in `Update()`.

I've been trying to solve this for a long time, and I would appreciate it if you could guide me.

This is my Player Controller code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerInputActions controls;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Animator anim;
    private bool facingRight = true;
    private float moveInput;
    public Transform feetPos;
    public float jumpInput;
    public float speed;

    [SerializeField] float JumpVelocity = 5;
    float JumpPressedRemember = 0;
    [SerializeField] float JumpPressedRememberTime = 0.2f;

    float GroundedRemember = 0;

    [SerializeField] float GroundedRememberTime = 0.25f;
    [SerializeField] float HorizontalAcceleration = 1;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float HorizontalDampingBasic = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float HorizontalDampingWhenStopping = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float HorizontalDampingWhenTurning = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] [Range(0, 1)] float JumpHeight = 0.5f;

    private void Awake()
    {
        controls = new PlayerInputActions();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void OnMove(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        moveInput = context.ReadValue<float>();
    }

    public void OnJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        JumpVelocity = context.ReadValue<float>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);
      
        if (facingRight == false && moveInput > 0)
        {
            Flip();
        }
        else if (facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
        {

            Flip();
        }
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;
        Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
        Scaler.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = Scaler;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 GroundedBoxCheckPosition = (Vector2)transform.position + new Vector2(0, -0.01f);
        Vector2 GroundedBoxCheckScale = (Vector2)transform.localScale + new Vector2(-0.02f, 0);
        bool Grounded = Physics2D.OverlapBox(GroundedBoxCheckPosition, transform.localScale, 0);

        GroundedRemember -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (Grounded)
        {
            GroundedRemember = GroundedRememberTime;
        }

        JumpPressedRemember -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (controls.Player.Jump.triggered)
        {
            JumpPressedRemember = JumpPressedRememberTime;
        }

        if (controls.Player.Jump.triggered)
        {
            if (rb.velocity.y > 0)
            {
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * JumpHeight);
            }
        }

        if ((JumpPressedRemember > 0) && (GroundedRemember > 0))
        {
            JumpPressedRemember = 0;
            GroundedRemember = 0;
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, JumpVelocity);
        }

        float HorizontalVelocity = rb.velocity.x;
        HorizontalVelocity += Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")) < 0.01f)
            HorizontalVelocity *= Mathf.Pow(1f - HorizontalDampingWhenStopping, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
        else if (Mathf.Sign(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")) != Mathf.Sign(HorizontalVelocity))
            HorizontalVelocity *= Mathf.Pow(1f - HorizontalDampingWhenTurning, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
        else
            HorizontalVelocity *= Mathf.Pow(1f - HorizontalDampingBasic, Time.deltaTime * 10f);

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(HorizontalVelocity, rb.velocity.y);
    }
}
```

And this is the code that I downloaded from GitHub.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField]
LayerMask lmWalls;

[SerializeField]
float fJumpVelocity = 5;

Rigidbody2D rigid;

float fJumpPressedRemember = 0;
[SerializeField]
float fJumpPressedRememberTime = 0.2f;

float fGroundedRemember = 0;
[SerializeField]
float fGroundedRememberTime = 0.25f;

[SerializeField]
float fHorizontalAcceleration = 1;
[SerializeField]
[Range(0, 1)]
float fHorizontalDampingBasic = 0.5f;
[SerializeField]
[Range(0, 1)]
float fHorizontalDampingWhenStopping = 0.5f;
[SerializeField]
[Range(0, 1)]
float fHorizontalDampingWhenTurning = 0.5f;

[SerializeField]
[Range(0, 1)]
float fCutJumpHeight = 0.5f;

void Start ()
{
    rigid = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update ()
{
    Vector2 v2GroundedBoxCheckPosition = (Vector2)transform.position + new Vector2(0, -0.01f);
    Vector2 v2GroundedBoxCheckScale = (Vector2)transform.localScale + new Vector2(-0.02f, 0);
    bool bGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapBox(v2GroundedBoxCheckPosition, v2GroundedBoxCheckScale, 0, lmWalls);

    fGroundedRemember -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (bGrounded)
    {
        fGroundedRemember = fGroundedRememberTime;
    }

    fJumpPressedRemember -= Time.deltaTime;
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        fJumpPressedRemember = fJumpPressedRememberTime;
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump"))
    {
        if (rigid.velocity.y > 0)
        {
            rigid.velocity = new Vector2(rigid.velocity.x, rigid.velocity.y * fCutJumpHeight);
        }
    }

    if ((fJumpPressedRemember > 0) && (fGroundedRemember > 0))
    {
        fJumpPressedRemember = 0;
        fGroundedRemember = 0;
        rigid.velocity = new Vector2(rigid.velocity.x, fJumpVelocity);
    }

    float fHorizontalVelocity = rigid.velocity.x;
    fHorizontalVelocity += Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")) < 0.01f)
        fHorizontalVelocity *= Mathf.Pow(1f - fHorizontalDampingWhenStopping, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
    else if (Mathf.Sign(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")) != Mathf.Sign(fHorizontalVelocity))
        fHorizontalVelocity *= Mathf.Pow(1f - fHorizontalDampingWhenTurning, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
    else
        fHorizontalVelocity *= Mathf.Pow(1f - fHorizontalDampingBasic, Time.deltaTime * 10f);

    rigid.velocity = new Vector2(fHorizontalVelocity, rigid.velocity.y);
}
}
```

Comment: Should `OnJump` be setting the jump velocity? It seems like you should have a boolean value that gets set to `true`, e.g., `jumped`. Then use that in your calculations instead of the `triggered` property on the controls. I ran into a lot of issues with expectations vs. actual when working with the controls. If you can confirm your intent, I can come up with an official sample.

Comment: `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");` should be changed to `moveInput.X;`, too. GetAxisRaw should not be used since you already get the movement value from the `OnMove` method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think maybe I should use "jumpInput" instead of "JumpVelocity" in "OnJump". Everything in this code is messed up. In fact, I downloaded a player controller code from Git Hub to use it as a guide but the problem was that it was using old input system. Despite this, I copied that code and pasted it to this one. And that's why everything is complicated in here. I added "jumpInput" before but "JumpVelocity" is for the other player controller.

Comment: Could you please show me an example for that boolean value? I understand what you mean but I want to write it correctly so I'm asking.

Comment: @ps2goat Also, I changed Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"); to moveInput.X; but I got an error saying 'float' does not contain a definition for 'x'. How can I define 'x'?

Comment: I didn't want to use PlayerInput component but somewhere I read it is an easier way than coding everything yourself. But now I think perhaps it was not a good idea to use that component, because it is making the work even harder.

Comment: The new input system is a bit easier for some things, but it is a pain to set up. I had a whole Twitter thread about my problems, and then one day my problems were solved. Something to do with a bug in the UI.  Anyway, I can whip up a sample later tonight.

Comment: I agree. It is a real pain to set up. Thank you so much for your help. I know I will solve these problems soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wanted to try this out because I hadn't yet implemented jumping in my own game, and I wanted to see how simple it could be with the New Input System. I rather enjoyed this, and one of the coolest parts about event-based input is that you don't have to put everything into a single method!

Please note that I did this in 3D-- I don't have a 2D game set up yet. I assume you may need to adjust the axis on which force is applied, as well as use the RigidBody2D and 2D colliders.

For setup, you need a collider on your terrain, and a collider and RigidBody on your character. (I assume you have this set up, but this is for others who find the answer.) The collider on the terrain is needed so the player doesn't fall through the terrain. The collider on the player is for the same reason. The RigidBody allows for physics and calculations around gravity and mass, etc. (You must have gravity enabled for this example!)

So this example will allow us to apply a force to the player in an upward direction, and then gravity will bring the character back to the terrain.

First, note that when you create controls and have a C# class auto-generated, you need to have your class inherit that. Your controls class is called `PlayerInputActions`. I don't see the "Action Map" name, so I will use mine. In the GUI, mine is called "AvatarDefault". The action is called "Jump". If you inspect the auto-generated C# class, you will find the namespace, interface, and methods. My action map becomes an interface when generated, and is named `IAvatarDefaultActions`. Since you don't list your ActionMap name, I will use mine. Replace it with yours in your code.

Import your namespace if necessary, and inherit the interface on your player input class.

> Some code removed for brevity!

```
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour, PlayerInputActions.IAvatarDefaultActions {
    
    // allow changing the force applied when jumping in the editor.
    // note that for a mass of 1 on my character, I had to use a value of about 300
    [SerializeField]
    private float jumpForce;

    // track our instance of controls
    private PlayerInputActions controls;

    // in awake, we need to create a new instance of controls
    // and bind the action events.

    private void Awake()
    {
        controls = new PlayerInputActions();
        // the auto-generated class takes care of all the event registration we need to do!
        // without this, we won't get event notifications.
        controls.AvatarDefault.SetCallbacks(this);
    }

    // I chose to explicitly implement the interface for clarity (since I'm still newish)
    void PlayerInputActions.IAvatarDefaultActions.OnJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        // there are several phases, but the only one we should care about is whether
        // the action was performed or not. (You can use an if statement, if you want)
        switch (context.phase)
        {
            case InputActionPhase.Performed:
                // to separate event handlers from actual code, I've been putting the
                // actual logic in a separate method
                this.Jump();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        // you can play around with the ForceMode here, and probably need
        // to use a Vector2 since you're working with 2D.
        // in this example, though, it's applying the jump force on the y axis.
        // a positive value will make the character thrust upward.
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * this.jumpForce, ForceMode.Force);
    }

    // You should also have these two methods
    public void OnEnable()
    {
        controls.Enable();
    }

    public void OnDisable()
    {
        controls.Disable();
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps. If not, I can attempt to set up a 2D environment. It looks like the only thing that would change for 2D would be to use `ForceMode2D.Force`.

For reference, this is what my input setup looks like. I have "Jump" set to a "Button" action type, because I only care if it was pressed or not.
[image]

### Movement fixes update

As for the issue with `movement`, the input system is meant to easily pass a Vector2 for stick and D-pad movement. so the value coming through would have `movement.x` and `movement.y` to get the horizontal and vertical input, respectively.

This is how I have my movement action set up:
[image]

And this is how I have the `Up` control mapped to the `W` key. (The others are similar, but mapped to the appropriate keys.)
[image]

Here's my code to set the movement variable.

```
    private Vector2 moveInput;

    void PlayerInputActions.IAvatarDefaultActions.OnMove(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        moveInput= context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    }
```

And now you just use `moveInput.x` in your update code for the horizontal value!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I did everything you said but still I have some problems and questions. First, I have too many variables for jump for example jumpInput, jumpForce and JumpVelocity and they're making things complicated. Second, I got some weird errors and I don't know what they're for. For example an error for " controls.Player.SetCallbacks(this);" or this "  else if (Mathf.Sign(moveInput.x)) != Mathf.Sign(HorizontalVelocity);
            HorizontalVelocity *= Mathf.Pow(1f - HorizontalDampingWhenTurning, Time.deltaTime * 10f);"

Comment: The error says Cannot implicitly convert type float to 'bool but the moveInput is a Vector2.

Comment: And the error of "controls.Player.SetCallbacks(this);" says Argument 1: cannot convert from 'PlayerController' to 'PlayerInputActions'.

Comment: For the jump variables, try taking everything out except what I have in my example. I'm not sure if you need velocity, but you could certainly add that back in later. `SetCallbacks` should be auto generated. If you select your player controls file in the "Project" window, do you have "Generate C# Class" selected in the Inspector window? I have version 1.0.0 of the new input system package installed on my machine.

Comment: I also have two more questions. Do I need to write the same code as OnJump for OnMove? And Do I have to write OnEnable and OnDisale for Move?

Comment: Okay, thanks. Yes, I have "Generate C# Class" selected and I have a class called PlayerInputActions for it.

Comment: `OnEnable` and `OnDisable` are on your controls, not on each action. So no, just the one method each for enable/disable. I have the sample `OnMove` code at the bottom of my answer, that goes in the same `PlayerController` class. I added it as an update, so I left it separate since the original problem was with the jumping functionality. As for the generated C# class, you can view that from the asset folder. If you open the script, you should have a "SetCallbacks" method in the generated script. (Don't change it, because it will be overwritten the next time you make changes to your controls.)

Comment: I think I need jumpVelocity because I used it in some lines. Perhaps I need to change its name to something else. As you can see in the code, I also have a "public float speed".

Comment: That's what `jumpForce` is for. If you want to calculate a value based on velocity, use whatever logic you like to replace `jumpForce` in the `Jump` method. For this example, you can start the jump independent of the movement logic.

Comment: I deleted both jumpVelocity and speed and replaced them with jumpForce and now I just have 1 error and that is "moveInput.x" and since it is a else if statement, it says you cannot convert float to bool. moveInput is a Vector2. What can I do for this?

Comment: based on your original code, it looks like you have a parenthesis in the wrong place and your variable name changed (it was `fHorizontalVelocity`, missing the `f` in your error code in the comments).  Try changing that `if else` and line beneath it to `else if (Mathf.Sign(moveInput.x) != Mathf.Sign(HorizontalVelocity)) { fHorizontalVelocity *= Mathf.Pow(1f - HorizontalDampingWhenTurning, Time.deltaTime * 10f)};`

Comment: Yes, I changed it because I thought It's weird but I will change it again. Also I found another error for  controls.Player.SetCallbacks(this); and it underlined "this" and says cannot convert from playercontroller to PlayerInputActions. *EDIT* Thank you, you're right. I had a paranthesis in the wrong place and only one error left.

Comment: Then you're missing the inheritance on the controller class. In my code, it comes after `class <classname> : Monobehaviour, <interface>`. Based on your code in that last comment, you need something like `public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour, PlayerInputActions.IPlayer`. If you look at the definition for the value to pass into `SetCallbacks`, it will tell you what the expected value is. You can also see what it expects by going into the generated class and searching for `SetCallbacks`. Whatever the name is, your class needs to inherit that interface.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I can move my character. But when I press jump, my character jumps at a low height and then I can't move it anymore. Maybe there is a problem with Input Actions. But at least now I can move it and If I solve this, I think I don't have any problems :) Also, I wanted to ask your opinion about something. Do you think it's okay to have both keyboard and gamepad working at the same time or it's better to have only one of them working? (ex. If I'm using gamepad, keyboard is not working until the gamepad disconnected)

Comment: I haven't gotten far enough to determine which is better. My initial setup was for a single person playing with whatever their device may be. According to Unity, it may be better to have one control scheme (`Player`, e.g.) per set of inputs. So Mouse & Keyboard could be one, gamepad could be another. I won't be working more on that until I get into multiplayer.

Comment: As far as the low jump height, change your values that you pass into `AddForce`. Like I said, I had to have a value of about 300 for a standard looking game jump. As for movement, what do you mean you can't move it anymore? You can't move during a jump?

Comment: When I start the game, I can move the character perfectly but when I press jump button on keyboard or gamepad, I can't move it anymore and the character just faces right and left. If I press jump button rapidly I can move around a little bit! I know, it's weird.

Comment: I fixed the problem. All I did was deleting "rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput.x * jumpForce, rb.velocity.y);" in FixedUpdate. It prevented the player from moving after jumping. Also, I realized that when I change the value JumpForce in inspector, it won't change in the game and still jumps at a low height. Maybe there is something wrong with the code.  And for AddForce, I use this  "rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * this.jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Force);". How can I change the value?

Comment: It's not jumping, when I press jump, It just moves upward without leaving the ground. I think the problem is "(controls.Player.Jump.triggered)".

Comment: And also, since moveInput is a Vector2, how can I use it when I want to use If statement for animation? I mean it can't be equal or more than zero when I want to play an animation.

Comment: Perhaps you should create a new question with your new code, then tag me on it.

Answer (score 0):

From the unity documentation and my small knowledge of unity, it seems you are using it right, however on the example they run `float speed = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime;` so maybe if you're having issues try using that line and see what changes. If you're struggling with key mapping it also says you can edit it in Edit->Settings->Input.

Documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html

Comment: That's the old input system. The new Input System is very different. Though I now see it in the OP's code. That's also probably part of the problem.

Comment: Is time.deltatime still used? I remember that being quite important for velocity etc when I watched brackeys tutorials.

Comment: Yes, that should still be used to scale according to time between updates, but I think there's more wrong with this algorithm than just that.

Comment: Personally, Brackeys tutorials have never solved my problems except once. In general I have not found an useful tutorial about the new input system and I'm wondering how they are less than the old system tutorials.